# Gdb hardware watchpoint error on android

Tags: debugging, android, arm, gdb, breakpoint

After failing to find a solution to [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/lldb-debugging-on-android) I have started using Gdb  and have encountered another error.

`Gdb`fails to set hardware watchpoint when I'm remote debugging a rooted `arm7-a` target. It supports hardware watchpoints and breakpoints according to the Technical references manual.

> **Breakpoints and watchpoints**
>
> The processor supports six breakpoints, four watchpoints, and a
> standard Debug Communications Channel (DCC). Four of the breakpoints
> match only to virtual address and the other two match against either
> virtual address or context ID, or Virtual Machine Identifier (VMID).
> All the watchpoints can be linked to two breakpoints to enable a
> memory request to be trapped in a given process context.

If i set a hardware watchpoint on `gdb` then it says failed to set hardware watchpoint. But if i change the parameter using:

```
set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0
```

I can set the software watchpoint successfully but it is very slow and laggy. I really dont understand why its failing. Could it be because the watchpoint is not correctly aligned?

The processor is an arm cortex-a7 and i can link the technical references manual if needed. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this processor doesn't support hardware watchpoints or the debuggers dont have support for hardware watchpoints for my processor. After trying to set a watchpoint with `lldb` lldb reported that there are `0` available hardware watchpoints. So there is no way around this one.